# How to reframe a times series data-frame by adding 3 columns that will contain the information of row-level partition of the data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

[image: row-level partition of time series data-frame and capture information accordingly]

How to reframe a times series data-frame by adding 3 columns that will contain the information of row-level partition of the data-frame?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Scott Boston would you please help me on this. I used your code mentioned below to populate group column. but how can I populate/derive next two columns 'count' and 'duration' as shown above?

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':pd.date_range('2022-05-01 00:01:00', periods=17, freq='T'),
                   'fault_code':['A']*4+['B']*3+['A']*2+['C']*5+['B']*2+['A']*1,
                   'pulse': 1
                  })
display(df)

df['group'] = (df['fault_code'] != df['fault_code'].shift()).cumsum()
display(df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get each of your columns with `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df["group"] = df.groupby(df["fault_code"].ne(df["fault_code"].shift()).cumsum()).ngroup().add(1)
df["count"] = df.groupby("group")["timestamp"].transform("count")
df["duration"] = df.groupby("group")["timestamp"].transform(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()+pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)).total_seconds()/60)

>>> df
             timestamp fault_code  pulse  group  count  duration
0  2022-05-01 00:01:00          A      1      1      4       4.0
1  2022-05-01 00:02:00          A      1      1      4       4.0
2  2022-05-01 00:03:00          A      1      1      4       4.0
3  2022-05-01 00:04:00          A      1      1      4       4.0
4  2022-05-01 00:05:00          B      1      2      3       3.0
5  2022-05-01 00:06:00          B      1      2      3       3.0
6  2022-05-01 00:07:00          B      1      2      3       3.0
7  2022-05-01 00:08:00          A      1      3      2       2.0
8  2022-05-01 00:09:00          A      1      3      2       2.0
9  2022-05-01 00:10:00          C      1      4      5       5.0
10 2022-05-01 00:11:00          C      1      4      5       5.0
11 2022-05-01 00:12:00          C      1      4      5       5.0
12 2022-05-01 00:13:00          C      1      4      5       5.0
13 2022-05-01 00:14:00          C      1      4      5       5.0
14 2022-05-01 00:15:00          B      1      5      2       2.0
15 2022-05-01 00:16:00          B      1      5      2       2.0
16 2022-05-01 00:17:00          A      1      6      1       1.0
```

###### Edit:

If you only want to fill the count and duration for the first row of each group, you can further do:

```
df[["count","duration"]] = df[["count","duration"]].where(~df["group"].duplicated()).fillna('')

>>> df
              timestamp fault_code  pulse  group count duration
0  2022-05-01  00:01:00          A      1      1   4.0      4.0
1  2022-05-01  00:02:00          A      1      1               
2  2022-05-01  00:03:00          A      1      1               
3  2022-05-01  00:04:00          A      1      1               
4  2022-05-01  00:05:00          B      1      2   3.0      3.0
5  2022-05-01  00:06:00          B      1      2               
6  2022-05-01  00:07:00          B      1      2               
7  2022-05-01  00:08:00          A      1      3   2.0      2.0
8  2022-05-01  00:09:00          A      1      3               
9  2022-05-01  00:10:00          C      1      4   5.0      5.0
10 2022-05-01  00:11:00          C      1      4               
11 2022-05-01  00:12:00          C      1      4               
12 2022-05-01  00:13:00          C      1      4               
13 2022-05-01  00:14:00          C      1      4               
14 2022-05-01  00:15:00          B      1      5   2.0      2.0
15 2022-05-01  00:16:00          B      1      5               
16 2022-05-01  00:17:00          A      1      6   1.0      1.0
```

Comment: Lol, you do this with the above code ;). Lookup documentation and examples for `groupby`.

Comment: which documentation do u refer, thank you

Comment: here the code populates values for each batch/group for columns 'count' and 'duration', but if I want a single pair of 'count' & 'duration' for each batch/group then what should I do? as shown in attached screen shot.